# Creating an Automator service to add email messages to Reminders.app

Tags: mail.app, macos, automator, reminders

I've created an Automator service that creates a reminder based on the selected text.  What I really want is to create a keyboard shortcut that gets the same result that you get by dragging an email into the Reminders.app.

The service I have just uses the text to create the title of the reminder, but when you drag an email into Reminders.app it uses the subject of the email as the title and adds a link to the email its self.

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut for this action or an Automator service?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the keyboard shortcut, but I just finished an Actionscript that adds the email Subject as the Reminder Title, the email Body as the Reminder Content and then adds a link to the actual email at the bottom of the Reminder. Hope this helps!

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Calendar" to activate
tell application "Calendar"
    set miniaturized of window 1 to true
    tell application "Mail"
        set theSelection to selection
        set theMessage to item 1 of theSelection
        set theurl to "message://%3c" & theMessage's message id & "%3e"
        set thedes to theMessage's content & "Show in Mail " & "message://%3c" & theMessage's message id & "%3e"
        set input to theMessage's subject
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Calendar"
    tell application "Reminders"
        make new reminder at end with properties {name:input, body:thedes}
        tell application "Reminders" to activate
    end tell
end tell
return input
```

end run

Comment: Thanks Kevin for providing this script.  I like the idea of adding the body of the message to the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut for a service. In System Preferences, Keyboard and Mouse, Keyboard Shortcuts: add a new shortcut for All Applications (if you want to use it everywhere). Make sure to match the services menu text exactly, including case and spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a service that runs an AppleScripts and can be activated with a keyboard shortcut.

First I add the **Get Selected Mail Messages** action with Messages selected in the options.  Then I used the **Run AppleScript** action with the following AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Mail"
    set _sel to selection
    set _links to {}

    set the _message to item 1 ¬
        of the _sel
    set theSubject to subject of _message
    set message_id to the message id of the _message
end tell

set message_url to "message://%3c" & message_id & "%3e"
set end of _links to message_url
set the clipboard to (_links as string)

set theBody to the clipboard

tell application "Reminders"
    set theReminder to make new reminder with properties {name:theSubject, body:theBody, priority:1}

end tell

return input
```

end run

This doesn't add the body of the email to Reminders.app, but it does use the subject as the reminder's title and adds a link to the email message in the reminder's note field.

Answer (score 0):

I collated answers from this thread and elsewhere into a "Email reply reminder" workflow which sets a reminder to reply to an email , [its on github here](https://github.com/csandeep/EmailReplyReminder)